# i keep getting a type error for an undefined function. any ideas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

i keep getting a type error in the last block of this code, which is canvas 3. any ideas? i'm assuming there's a typo somewhere but can't find it.  unless something is double named by mistake...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hR6dC/

```
// Canvas 1 
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context = canvas1.getContext("2d");

photo = document.getElementById("red");

function drawImage() {
context.drawImage(photo, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener("load", drawImage, false);

// Canvas 2
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

context2.fillStyle = "darkRed"; 
context2.fillRect(0, 2, 800, 500);
context2.moveTo(0, 0);
context2.lineTo(400, 300);


// Canvas 3 
var canvas3 = document.getElementById("canvas3");
var context3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");

photo3 = document.getElementById("red2");

function drawImageTile() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        for (var y =0; y < 6; y++ ) {
            context3.drawImageTile(photo3, x * 100, y * 75, 100, 75);
        }
    }

}

window.addEventListener("load", drawImageTile, false);
```

Comment: I have tried your code on jsFiddle and I don't get an error. http://jsfiddle.net/hR6dC/

Comment: @logikal weird... here is the full error: "[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'context3.drawImageTile(photo3, x * 100, y * 75, 100, 75)')
 drawImageTile (script.js, line 34)"

Comment: Could you also post the HTML, mostly the canvas tags and the element with the ID of "red2"

Comment: sure. <img src="red2.jpg" id="red2" alt="red2">

Comment: so when i switch drawImageTile back to drawImage, canvas3 works but canvas1 disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

canvas.getContext does not have the drawImageTile() method, do you mean drawImage() ?

`context.drawImage(img,x,y);`

Read more: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Comment: ah that might be it. but can i have two draw image functions? i changed the name so it didn't conflict. but is that incorrect?

Comment: keep your drawImageTile() function the same, however drawImage() is a method of canvas.context, I assume you are wanting to call this drawImage method

Comment: correct... can you clarify your suggestion? appreciate the help.

Comment: I had to comment out the window.load eventlistener because it wasn't working on jsfiddle.

Comment: ah thank you! i see what i did. had drawImageTile when it should have been drawImage. appreciate your help.